# Vitest/Jest tests to extend/implement upon another test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, vitest

We have in our vue-project lots of injected services. We also use Vitest framework to test our code. Each time we create a test file we have to setup and mock the environment adding all the services, and dependencies, and plugins (Pinja, vuetify, rouger... etc), which is a huge boilerplate code I'd rather avoid rewriting if possible. Thus, I'm wondering if it's possible to create a separate file where all the services, dependencies, and plugins are added, and simply create a new test file that extends/implements the one with all the dependencies and just write the tests (similar to how classes inherit)?

Comment: It sounds like you are just asking how to create a module? If you don't want to repeat yourself, then require these services somewhere else. Then import testServices from "stuff"; and use testServices.Pinja, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: It isn't something a module can do. Jest tests aren't classes. So there is nothing to extend. You want a ParentTest that does a bunch of setup and teardown. You then extend this ParentTest over and over again. This happens in other languages/environments, not so with node/javascript/typescript/jest.